# How to index every 1000 number together

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table with a 'billnumber' column (INT 11)

billnumber value may changed every 3 or 4 records so if I index a 1M record I will have a 250K index

What I want is anyway to index every 1000 billnumber together
- from 1 to 1000 
- from 1001 to 2000

Comment: Yes, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I didn't find my answer in this pots
thanks for your help

Comment: Try harder!!!!!

Comment: I need a direct answer if u have ... If not thanks for your effort

Comment: @AhmedTaha The link in the first comment wasn't supposed to answer your question, but to show you how to improve your question to make it on-topic and answerable.

Comment: Thanks tollens but english is not my first language sometimes i can't explain what is going in my mind :) thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there actually a problem?

`INDEX(billnumber)` is non-unique, this will return 3 or 4 rows without difficulty:

```
SELECT ...
    WHERE bill_number = 1234
```

If you want to select 1..1000, simply do

```
SELECT ...
    WHERE bill_number BETWEEN 1 AND 1000;
```

Both are efficient.

Keep in mind, a data base table *has no order*.  To get the rows ordered, you *must* use `ORDER BY`.

Meanwhile, `INDEXes` try to make `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` efficient.

Comment: And yes it is not a problem i just worried about 'select' performance

Comment: Do address select performance, we need the actual `SELECT` (though we may suggest changes to improve performance) and the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` (though we may suggest index change and/or datatype changes).